# is it possible to project the same content in multiple mat-steps?

Tags: angular, mat-stepper, angular-content-projection

I am trying to use `mat-stepper` and the layout I am trying to make has the same content on both steps..

when on step 1, it would look like:
| *[step 1] do this* -- [step 2] do that | |
| -------- | -------------- |
|  this content is in both steps | ...unique step 1 content... |

when on step 2, it would look like:

| [step 1] do this -- *[step 2] do that* |  |
| --- | --- |
| this content is in both steps | ...unique step 2 content... |

So I am wondering, is there a way to accomplish this with content projection?

I was hoping I could just do something like:

```
<mat-stepper>
  <mat-step label="do this">
    <ng-content select="[stuff]"></ng-content>
    <p>unique step 1 stuff...</p>
  </matstep>
  <mat-step label="do that">
    <ng-content select="[stuff]"></ng-content>
    <p>unique step 2 stuff...</p>
  </matstep>
</mat-stepper>
<ng-template stuff>
  ...shared content...
</ng-template>
```

but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mat-stepper  like this:

```
<mat-stepper>
  <mat-step label="do this">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="sharedContent"></ng-container>
    <p>unique step 1 stuff...</p>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="do that">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="sharedContent"></ng-container>
    <p>unique step 2 stuff...</p>
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>

<ng-template #sharedContent>
  ...shared content...
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use embed a template ref using [`*ngTemplateOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) with `<ng-container>` like this:

```js
<mat-stepper>
  <mat-step label="do this">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stuff"/>
    <p>unique step 1 stuff...</p>
  </matstep>
  <mat-step label="do that">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stuff"/>
    <p>unique step 2 stuff...</p>
  </matstep>
</mat-stepper>
<ng-template #stuff>
  ...shared content...
</ng-template>
```